# unable to compile c++ code in macbook due to __GLIBC__ issue

Tags: c++, macos, gcc

g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g threads.cpp -o threads.out

```
In file included from threads.cpp:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:37:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:215:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:401:32: error: use of undeclared identifier '_ISspace'
    static const mask space  = _ISspace;
                               ^
Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:402:32: error: use of undeclared identifier '_ISprint'
    static const mask print  = _ISprint;
                               ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:403:32: error: use of undeclared identifier '_IScntrl'
    static const mask cntrl  = _IScntrl;
                               ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:404:32: error: use of undeclared identifier '_ISupper'
    static const mask upper  = _ISupper;
                               ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:405:32: error: use of undeclared identifier '_ISlower'
    static const mask lower  = _ISlower;
                               ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:406:32: error: use of undeclared identifier '_ISalpha'
    static const mask alpha  = _ISalpha;
```

can you please help me to resolve this __locale issue while compiling the c++ code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void fun(void)
{
    cout << "Vaule " << 10 << endl;
}

int main()
{
    thread t1(fun);
    thread t2(fun);
    return 0;
}
```

compiling command:
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g thread.cpp -o thread.out

Comment: Have you tried using clang?

Comment: Please show the output of `g++ --version`.

Comment: Unless it was installed from hombrew (or some other package manager) g++ on macOS is an alias to clang++ that also uses an older Standard Library. I have no source to confirm this, but given how it behaves sometimes, and the information it spits out when you do view `g++ --version`, it seems a reasonable conclusion to me. Try clang++ and see if it still occurs. I can't remember if you need to use `-pthread` as a compile option on macOS, but it's a quick thing to check.

Comment: @G.M.

` sekharpa : g++ --version 
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
Thread model: POSIX
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin`

Comment: @sweenish
I have also tried compiling with clang and clang++, still the same issue. 
having compiled with -lptherad also giving same errors.

Comment: Please show your code and provide the command(s) you use to compile/link.  Note that you might have to specify `-std=c++11` explicitly with that version of clang.

Comment: @G.M
I have included the code and compilation command in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Two things fix the problem you're having.

Thing the first, add the compiler option `-pthread`. My compile command: `clang++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -pthread main.cpp`

Thing the second, join your threads before ending the program.

```cpp
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
```

Something it does not fix, is that your `std::cout` statement will likely be jumbled because the threads simply dump their data into the single stream as they please. For an example, my output was the following:

```
Vaule Vaule 10
10
```

In order to fix that, you'll likely need to place a lock(mutex) around the `std::cout` statement.

As I said in my comment, I do not recommend using `g++` unless you installed it yourself. The command you're using is an alias that doesn't behave, because of some text you left out.

```
❯ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Contrast with clang++

```
❯ clang++ --version
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Of note in the g++ section is the 'Configured with' line. It uses a Standard Library from gcc 4.2.1, which is pre-C++11. You should not have left that information out.

Comment: I have tried the same steps you have mentioned. Still getting the same error.
It's with my mac book missing some configuration, that I don't know how to fix.